# Full height input in td with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See http://jsbin.com/sawofo/2/edit.  I am trying to fill a table cell with an input, using bootstrap's css, but I am left with a gap that I can't get rid of.

My html snippet is:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="with-input"><input class="form-control tall" type="text" value="text"></td>
      <td class="tall">XX</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the CSS which allows the input to stretch is:

```
td {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

td.tall {
  height: 100px;
}

input.tall {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100% !important;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But there is still a gap at the bottom of the input that I can't get rid of.  It appears to have something to do with bootstrap setting

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

but I can't figure out how to reverse the effect without completely removing bootstrap.  If I set the `td` to use `content-box`, the height is fine but it overflows horizontally into the next cell.

Answer (score 0):

add `padding: 0;`

```
td {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

td.tall {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}

input.tall {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;//added
}
```

output

[**http://jsbin.com/kefibozapo/1/**](http://jsbin.com/kefibozapo/1/)

Comment: There is still a gap the bottom, although it is a lot smaller.  But the biggest problem is that I do actually padding within the `input`.

Comment: In my example I'm using a fixed height to illustrate the problem.  In my actual implementation the height changed because of other content, so I can't just hard-code the min-height of the `input` to the height of the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  It seems that for some reason the padding leaks from the child element to the `td`, so setting `padding: 10px` on the `input` also assigns it to the `td`.  The solution is to wrap the input in a `div` with style:

```
padding: 0;
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

E.g.: http://jsbin.com/sawofo/4/edit